# Add Background Color To Title Which Already Has Image Background

Tags: css

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/haymanpl/2kwozzj6/9/)

I have added a background image to the site title but also need to add a background to the site title text with minimal padding. When i add the title background color, it displays behind the background image where i need it to display behind the title so it floats over the title part of the image.

```
<header class="site-header"><div class="wrap"><div class="title-area"><p class="site-title"><a href="http://local.dev/">Lighter Background</a></p></div></div></header>

.site-title a { 
background: url('https://s24.postimg.org/i5zlke6mt/cropped_Snow_2.jpg') no-repeat !important; 
}

.site-title a {
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );  
    padding: 3% 10%;
    margin: 0 0 3% 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; 
    color: #fff;
}
```

The 1st CSS rule is generated by the theme and website application. The 2nd is added to the style sheet manually.

Edit: Like this https://divibooster.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/divi-theme-semi-transparent-background.png

1. With a image background for the site header
2. The site title displayed over the site header image
3. And a background color background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );  behind the title.

Comment: you may add a hudge inset shado instead background-color: `.site-title a {box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}` or use multiple bg image inserting a single gradient

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear on what the desired outcome is?

Comment: You need to create another div for either your image or your title, and layer the title div on top of the image div. You probably want to make the color div opaque as well, otherwise the image won't show?

Please indent your html and use a plunker to demo the problem https://plnkr.co/

Answer (score 0):

I added some < mark style="background-color: blue;">< /mark> to your title to highlight it in a color. This should allow the color to be displayed in front of your image.

```
<header class="site-header"><div class="wrap"><div class="title-area"><p class="site-title"><a href="http://local.dev/"><mark style="background-color: blue;">Lighter Background</mark></a></p></div></div></header>

.site-title a { 
background: url('https://s24.postimg.org/i5zlke6mt/cropped_Snow_2.jpg') no-repeat !important; 
}

.site-title a {
    background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );  
    padding: 3% 10%;
    margin: 0 0 3% 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; 
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: This is a way to add color behind the text but I am unsure if it is your desired effect.

Comment: Actually looking for a CSS solution i can add to the style sheet rather than editing the HTML directly as its generated by the PHP in the parent theme.